# ECONNRESET in nativescript after adding Sass

Tags: sass, angular2-nativescript

I'm having problems after adding Sass to a Angular2 NativeScript project.

I get ECONNRESET when I run:
tns livesync ios --emulator --watch

I can reproduce this by creating a new project and add Sass.
1. Create new project: tns create test-project --ng
2. tns install sass
3. Add the three scss files _app-common.scss, app.android.scss, app.ios.scss as described in http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme#sass-usage.

The complete error I get in terminal:
   NativeScript debugger encountered Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=9  "Bad file descriptor".
   Error: read ECONNRESET
       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
       at TCP.onread (net.js:572:26)

Answer (score 0):

Follow those steps (Android/iOS):

1. Uninstall nativescript cli by executing npm uninstall -g nativescript
2. Clear the npm cache: npm cache clean
3. Install the latest CLI npm install -g nativescript
4. Remove the platforms folder in your project
5. Execute tns run android/iOS --emulator
6. Try tns livesync android/ios --emulator --watch

Please, could you upgrade your SDK and emulators & simulators to the latest version.